# why does putting multiple periods for a scanf input skip the next scanf functions?

Tags: c, scanf

why does putting multiple periods for a scanf input skip the next scanf functions.
example input: `b. b.`

```
int main (void) {

    char b[7] = " ";

    printf("This is: ");
    scanf(" %s", b);

    printf("This is 2nd: ");
    scanf(" %s", b);

    printf("This is 3rd: ");
    scanf(" %s", b);

    printf("\nThis is 4rth: %s\n", b);
    printf("This is 5th: %s", b);

    return 0;
}
```

//output

```
This is: b. b.

This is 2nd: This is 3rd:
```

Comment: Why do you think anything is being skipped?  I suspect your third scanf is blocked on a read.

Comment: Rather than typing input interactively, run the program as `echo b. b. | ./a.out`

Comment: `scanf`is blocking function

Comment: if you input just regular words without periods, it works fine and doesn't skip the scanf inputs

Comment: `%s` reads words delimited by whitespace. It doesn't treat periods differently from any other characters.

Comment: You have 3 calls to `scanf()`, it's waiting for you to type a third word.

Comment: I just tried it entering input `a b`, I got the same result, it waited for another input.

Comment: The problem is the space and not the dots (full stop, period). The `%s` format skips white space, and then reads up to the next white space.  And it doesn’t discard what’s left onthe line; it reads it next.

Comment: ok that makes sense, I got the issue now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not the problem with the period, the skipping of the next `scanf` statement is because your input contains Space.

Please check the link explaining- [Taking String input with space in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-string-input-space-c-3-different-methods/)